# What's broken in my iPhone

Tags: iphone, battery, repair

I just got my friends' iPhone and he claims he's broken. So I sent it to a repair centre and they told me the logic board was broken. However, when I try to recharge the iPhone by plugging it in the wall, the Apple logo appears and it seems to be booting just fine.

Only, when I pull out the plug, the phone immediately shuts down, although the battery indicated it's fully charged. So I think not that the motherboard is broken, but that there's some kind of battery issue. I've tried replacing the battery, but that didn't work out. Another interesting thing is that the phone keeps rebooting. After booting, it shows the "connect to iTunes" screen, but after 5 minutes it's back to rebooting.

Is it really the (connection to the battery on the) motherboard or can you think of something else?

Comment: I don't believe anyone on this site would be better qualified to answer that question than the technician who has physical access to the device, given your type of problem.

Comment: Could be anything. Without physical access to the device it's hardly possible to say more.

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly not the connection of the battery to the logic board. You can test that with a simple continuity tester and your placing a new battery and getting the same symptoms means that unless you got a dud replacement that doesn't even begin to work in spec,

Without reading the voltage on the logic board to determine if the systme is shutting itself down due to a sensor failure rather than simply too low voltage being supplied.

I don't know what you are really looking to do, since unless you are prepared to repair a logic board itself by diagnosing and isolating the failure, does it really matter whether the CPU or a transistor or a current sensor or a supporting power manangement chip has been damaged? You can buy a new logic board and test things or pay to have someone that knows how to repair it fix the phone. I can think of a hundred things that could be wrong (start with picking traces on the logic board and you see how many things could be broken) but guessing why one phone has failed is not likely to help others here.

Not to come off as snarky, but there are dozens of things to check for sub component micro repair and some people do that very well. For most of us that would open an iPhone, it’s about swapping major components since we don’t want to pay for the skills and tools needed to really diagnose and repair these delicate components.

I hope this helps you make some decisions how to proceed with repair options or embarking on learning from this failed device after exhausting your tries to open and reconnect things a couple times.